# Adding a suffix from an attribute to magento product URL

Tags: attributes, url, ce-1.9.2.4

Have been going around in circles with this for a while now.

I am looking to add a block of text in the form of an attribute to the end of the URL.

What I am looking for in the end is:

```
https://www.magentostore.com/productURL?options[39]=35&options[40]=38
```

The code I have so far currently just loads the normal URL, without the attributes addition on the end:

```
<a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl(); ?><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getconfigdefaults(), 'configdefaults') ?>" class="btn btn-primary  btn-block btn-more" title="<?php echo $this->__('Buy & More Info') ?>">
```

Thanks for any help anyone can provide!